# Change capacity of sd card from 8GB to 1GB

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

I got 8GB SD Card and I want to make from this card 1GB sd card.

Why? Because I got barcode scanner and I can use only 1GB card.

I must change my 8GB card to 1gb but not only partition. It must be like brand new 1GB card.

is it possible?

Comment: It’s most likely about SD card standards, not about capacity. Just buy a compatible card. Should be pretty cheap too.

Comment: But I have a lot of bigger sd card

Comment: So what? If it doesn’t work now, it’s not compatible. The end.

Comment: If creating a 1 GB partition, and leaving the other 7 GB unallocated does not work then the card is simply not compatible with your barcode scanner.